# How do I run a command in bash from zsh (or some other shell) in one line?

Tags: bash

Say I am currently in my zsh shell. If I want to run a command in bash, I currently execute the following two commands.

```
exec /bin/bash
# Below is my bash command
help set
```

How do I achieve the above in one line without changing my shell to bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `bash -c`.

> `-c`
> Read and execute commands from the first non-option argument `command_string`, then exit. […]

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash))</sup>

```
bash -c 'help set'
```

---

Note in your example if you didn't use `exec` but invoked sole `/bin/bash`, the `zsh` process wouldn't be replaced by `bash`, it would wait until `bash` terminates. This means you could interactively do what you want to do in Bash, then invoke `exit` (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and you would find yourself in your old Zsh.

Comment: Note that the command (to be executed by bash) must be passed to `bash -c` as a single argument, with an extra layer of quoting/escaping protecting it. If it doesn't have single-quotes, just put single-quotes around it (e.g. `bash -c 'help set'`). If it does have single-quotes, then it's more complicated.